# How to select rows with max values in categories?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, max

I would like to use the aggregation for each ID key to select rows with max(day).

| ID | col1 | col2 | month | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AI1 | 5 | 2 | janv | 15 |
| AI2 | 6 | 0 | Dec | 16 |
| AI1 | 1 | 7 | March | 16 |
| AI3 | 9 | 4 | Nov | 18 |
| AI2 | 3 | 20 | Fev | 20 |
| AI3 | 10 | 8 | June | 06 |

Desired result:

| ID | col1 | col2 | month | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AI1 | 1 | 7 | March | 16 |
| AI2 | 3 | 20 | Fev | 20 |
| AI3 | 9 | 4 | Nov | 18 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that comes to my mind is to :

- Get the highest day for each ID (using *groupBy*)
- Append the value of the highest day to each line (with matching ID) using *join*
- Then a simple *filter* where the value of the two lines match

```py
# select the max value for each of the ID
maxDayForIDs = df.groupBy("ID").max("day").withColumnRenamed("max(day)", "maxDay")

# now add the max value of the day for each line (with matching ID)
df = df.join(maxDayForIDs, "ID")

# keep only the lines where it matches "day" equals "maxDay"
df = df.filter(df.day == df.maxDay)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of operation is done using window functions like
[`rank`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.rank.html#pyspark.sql.functions.rank),
[`dense_rank`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank.html#pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank)
or [`row_number`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.row_number.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number).

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('AI1', 5, 2, 'janv', '15'),
     ('AI2', 6, 0, 'Dec', '16'),
     ('AI1', 1, 7, 'March', '16'),
     ('AI3', 9, 4, 'Nov', '18'),
     ('AI2', 3, 20, 'Fev', '20'),
     ('AI3', 10, 8, 'June', '06')],
    ['ID', 'col1', 'col2', 'month', 'Day']
)
w = W.partitionBy('ID').orderBy(F.desc('Day'))
df = df.withColumn('_rn', F.row_number().over(w))
df = df.filter('_rn=1').drop('_rn')

df.show()
# +---+----+----+-----+---+
# | ID|col1|col2|month|Day|
# +---+----+----+-----+---+
# |AI1|   1|   7|March| 16|
# |AI2|   3|  20|  Fev| 20|
# |AI3|   9|   4|  Nov| 18|
# +---+----+----+-----+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple

```
   new= (df.withColumn('max',first('Day').over(w))#Order by day descending and keep first value in a group in max
          .where(col('Day')==col('max'))#filter where max=Day
          .drop('max')#drop max
          ).show()
```